# How do I change my bibliography to another language?

Tags: bibliographies, babel

I'm encountering a problem when using Overleaf. I've used \usepackage[dutch]{babel} and my table of contents and header of my bibliography is all Dutch, which is great. However, my bibliography itself, is in English.

For example when I quote a chapter in a book, the bibliography says chapter 582 or first edition, whereas it should say hoofdstuk (Dutch for chapter) 582 and first editie (Dutch for edition).

I've tried \bibliography{bib.bib}{dutch} , but that did not work.

Comment: With biblatex, you can have different languages. With classic bst files, not.

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: It depends a bit on the BibTeX style you're using, too, e.g. `apacite` does have Dutch support. Most BibTeX styles don't have multilingual language support.

Comment: I use Overleaf and bibliographystyle{unsrt}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `babelbib`, which has support for Afrikaans, Bahasa, Catalan, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English, Esperanto, Finnish, French,
Galician, German, Greek, Italian, Norwegian, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Serbian, Spanish, and Swedish. It provides translated versions of plain, alpha, unsrt and abbrv. With the option `fixlanguage` it assumes the language provided to `babel` is desired for the bibliography.

MWE (note that the `filecontents` part is not necessary, it's just to create a `.bib` file on the fly):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{mychapter,
    author = {Jan Jansen},
    title = {Interessante Verhandeling},
    chapter = {3},
    publisher = {ABC Boeken},
    year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\begin{document}
Zie \cite{mychapter}.

\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}  % replace \jobname with the name of your bib file
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked! I did however in addition need to change \usepackage{natbib} to \usepackage[numbers]{natbib} or otherwise I would get an error.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to create the .bib file?

Comment: @Twink I'm not really sure I understand your comment. Does it have to do with the current question or answer about changing the language for a bibliography made with `bibtex`? Or do you have a different question about bibliographies? If your comment was about this question, then you should clarify what you mean exactly. If it is a different question, then you should start a new question by pressing the 'Ask Question' button on the top of the page.